# Fast (approximate?) linear programming solver for few variables and many constraints

Tags: open-source, library, software-development, math, optimization

I'm writing some code in C++, and it turns out I need to solve an optimization problem which may be formulated using `m` variables and `n` linear constraints (i.e. constraint `i` is of the form `\sum_j a_{i,j} x_j  >= b_i` ; although if you don't know what linear programming is you can probably not answer this question).

It so happens, that the number of variables is quite small - say, less than 10 typically; but the number of constraints is much higher.

I need the solution to be fast - at least in expectation (hopefully no more than one pass over most constraints) - and I'm willing to pay in distance from the optimum for that.

Is there a library for this 'niche' of linear programming? If not, what would be generally fast linear programming libraries?

Requirements:

- Libre license
- Code available
- Works on Linux
- Works on x86_64
- Fast
- Gratis

Desired features:

- Really fast
- Can trade off accuracy for speed
- Multi-platform
- C++ rather than C
- Modern C++ rather than C++98/03
- Well-documented

Comment: If C++ is indeed not an absolute requirement, you can also look at open source Java Solvers, such as [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) and Choco, fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into COIN-OR's [CLP](https://github.com/coin-or/Clp). It's a C++ FOSS LP solver; beyond that I can't say much for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to discuss here:

1. The algorithm.
2. The implementation of (1) in a suitable language.

**The algorithm** is what determines the runtime and accuracy of the method. If you are willing to sacrifice accuracy, you would choose a method like [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method) over [Simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) (this is an example for illustrative purposes).

As for the **implementation** - seeing how these sort of problems are usually solved by matrix operations, you can use the classic go-to library for these things - [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/). Another possibility is the [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) package. If you want a demonstration of how to use the latter, take a look at [Octave's](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) [source code](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/affd44707573/libinterp/dldfcn/__glpk__.cc). Perhaps Octave's [documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Linear-Programming.html) on the topic might also be useful.

BTW, another way to make the tradeoff, regardless of the specific technique, is performing the computation in a reduced-precision datatype, e.g. `float32` and not `float64`.